# Qt how to break the LabelText of QInputDialog

Tags: qt

Here is my example code:

```
QInputDialog* inDialog = new QInputDialog();
inDialog->setMaximumWidth(100);
inDialog->setLabelText(QString("long and very long......you can say very long"));
```

The input box showing really long (as long as the string), I was expected the way to set word-wrap for the LabelText, but it seem QInputDialog has no method for that!!!

What can I do now? Write my own InputDialog class? Oh no...!
I hope there is a better way for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it myself, like this for example :

```
QString s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut" ;
QString wrapped ;
if(s.length()>35)
{
    wrapped = s.left(15) + QString(".....") + s.right(15) ;
}
else
{
    wrapped = s ;
}
inDialog->setLabelText(wrapped) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting with QT so this may not be the best way to get what you want but heres what I would do.

I would create my own custom input dialog which inherits QInputDialog. I would then override the setLabelText function to check if the string length is less than 100.

If it is less than 100 then you can go ahead and display it. If not then you can choose where to add yours dots and remove words in order to bring the size down.

Once its equal to 100 characters or less, you can display it.

I will try and write an example when I get home if you would like.

Comment: Looks like totem has written the code for you. I would personally add that function to a inherited QInputDialog.